# "A continuous map which is open but not closed"-can someone explain to me why this proof works?

Tags: general-topology, open-map

http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/continuous-maps-that-are-not-closed-or-not-open/

I need some explanation of a proof given in the above link. I'm looking at the proof that $f_1:(x,y)\longmapsto x$ is open but not closed. Why is it that they are able to use a different specific function $\varphi$ to show that the map is not closed? This might be a dumb question given that I'm in grad level topology, but what's the difference between a map and a function? Why is the different type of arrow ($\longmapsto$)  used there? Any help is much appreciated! I'm in over my head.

Edit: is $\varphi$ just being used to show that the set $C=${ $(x, \frac{1}{x})|x>0 $} is closed, while its image $f_1(C)=(0,\infty)$ is open, implying that $f_1$ is not closed?

Comment: Map and function mean the same thing and the new arrow is same as the ordinary arrow.

Comment: "This might be a dumb question given that I'm in grad level topology, but what's the difference between a map and a function?" - Did you take undergrad topology? Surely at some point the terms must have been used interchangeably...

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I'm sure they have been used interchangeably at some point, but I wasn't sure if there was some subtlety that only now is becoming relevant. I'm in a topology class where both undergraduates and graduates get lumped together. It's more like a remedial grad class, or an undergrad class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first few words of the article are "an open map is function" followed by a condition.  Then that article defines closed map.  Although just "map" is not defined, a reasonable approximation is that a map is a function.

One convention for defining a map is to use "$\longrightarrow$" ($\TeX$'s `\longrightarrow`) between the domain and codomain and "$\longmapsto$" ($\TeX$'s `\longmapsto`) to indicate the image of a point in the domain.  (Not everyone uses the long versions.  You will see `\rightarrow` and `\mapsto` used sometimes.)  The article you mention follows this convention.  For instance, there is

$$ \begin{array}{r|lcl}
f_1 : & \Bbb{R}^2 & \longrightarrow & \Bbb{R} \\
      & (x,y)     & \longmapsto     & x
\end{array}  \text{.}  $$

(I predict the writer has a macro that they use for this purpose.  Perhaps something like `\displayfunction{f_1}{\reals^2}{\reals}{(x,y)}{x}` was used here.)

This says $f_1$ is a function from $\Bbb{R}^2$ to $\Bbb{R}$ defined by $f_1(x,y) = x$.

The function $\varphi$ is introduced only to show that a certain set is closed.  That set, $C$, is the preimage of a closed set through a continuous map, so is closed.  Then we let $f_1$ act on $C$ and discover that its image through $f_1$ is not closed, so $f_1$ failed to preserve its closedness, so must not be a closed function.

Comment: Great! Thank you for the detailed response. Do you think that coming up with the closed set $C$ was a matter of it being common knowledge that this is how one solves the problem, cleverness, a particular method for finding an example of a closed set which $f_1$ maps to an open set, or are there numerous such examples of closed which $f_1$ would map to an open set? This proof is similar to what I need for my homework, but I'd rather not copy it exactly, unless it is \textit{the} answer.

Comment: @fung0359 : There are many choices of $C$ that work.  The diagram at the top of the page shows the graph of a function and how that function maps an open set to a half-open set.  The particular choice of $C$, the graph of the function $y = 1/x$ has the property that it is a closed set, but its projections onto the axes are open.  So asymptotic behaviour is used to avoid limit points in the projections onto the axes.  There are many ways to use asymptotes to do this, so there are many constructions that work.